# Regex selecting numbers

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to capture the numbers in the text below with regex. But it seems to fail on the last text, which only has one digit inside a parenthesis. I can't figure out why since my knowledge with Regex is limited.

Any suggestions?

**Regex**

```
[\s(](\d[\d,\.\s]+)
```

**Text**

```
This banana costs 0,5 usd from previous (50)
The toothbrush is worth 0,8 usd (1,5)
This orange costs 1 usd from previous 10 usd
My car is now worth 1 000 (1 800)
This apple now costs 1 usd (1)
```

**Results**

```
0,5     50
0,8     1,5
1       10
1 000   1 800
1
```

Link to regex101: https://regex101.com/r/uy9OOc/1

Comment: Because the character class `[\d,\.\s]+` matches at least 1 character PLUS the preceding single digit which is at least 2 characters. It would like this this `[\s(](\d[\d,.\s]*)\b` https://regex101.com/r/dSYiwW/1

Comment: Thansk a lot for a rocket fast reply! @Thefourthbird That certainly did the trick, thanks for the explanation and demonstration!

Comment: @barruntlek Maybe you can try `\d+(?:,\d+| \d+)?` https://regex101.com/r/SOYfQO/1

Comment: @AndrejKesely Yes or just `\b\d+(?:[., ]\d+)*\b` https://regex101.com/r/cx9iFf/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern matches at least 2 characters, being a digit and 1 or more times one of `\d` `,` `.` `\s`

You can match either a space or `(` and then capture a single digit followed by optionally repeating the chars in the character class.

```
[\s(](\d[\d,.\s]*)
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YjCscC/1).

If you don't want trailing spaces, dots or comma's:

```
[\s(](\d+(?:[\d,.\s]*\d)?)\b
```

**Explanation**

- `[\s(]` Match either a whitespace char or `(`
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\d+` Match 1+ digits
  - `(?:[\d,.\s]*\d)?` Optionally match one of the chars in the character class followed by a digit
- `)` Close group 1
- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QCEETE/1)